# Нужно вывести 8 записей. две первых надо с одной версткой вывести и еще 6 с другой

Tags: php

Нужно вывести 8 записей из таблицы. В один div блок две заметки (картинка, название, краткое описание и т.д.), а во второй div блок, еще шесть заметок (картинка и название).Уже задавал этот вопрос но так и не понял, объясните пожалуйста на коде.

```html
                    <?php if($brands): ?>
                    <div class="block-content">
                        <div class="container cf">
                            <div class="large b-row cf">
                                <!--Здесь выводится 2 первые заметки, с этим проблем нет, limit=2-->
                                <?php foreach($brands as $brand): ?>
                                <div class="column half b-col">
                                    <article>
                                        <a href="#"> </a>
                                        <h2 class="post-title"><a href="#"><?=$brand->title;?></a></h2>
                                        <div class="cf listing-meta meta below"> <span class="meta-item author"><?=$brand->title;?> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> 3</a></span></div>
                                        <div class="excerpt">
                                            <p><?=$brand->description;?></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </article>
                                </div>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </div>
                            <!--А как быть дальше и вывести еще 6 заметок из тойже таблицы ума неприлажу-->
                            <ul class="b-row posts-list thumb">
                                <li class="column half b-col">
                                    <article class="post cf">
                                        <a href="#"> </a>
                                        <div class="content">
                                            <a href="#"><?=$brand->title;?></a>
                                            <div class="cf listing-meta below"> <time datetime="2017-01-10T03:34:37+00:00" class="meta-item">Jan 10, 2017</time></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </article>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98448/discussion-on-question-by-----8----).

Comment: @RifmaMan Еще вопрос к вам, если я вставляю такой код, var dump выводит мне первые две записи,'<?php array_splice($brands, 2); ?>
                 <?php echo "<pre>";
                var_dump($brands);
                    echo "</pre>";?>' все верно! а как теперь мне вывести эти записи, без вар дампа? Нужен ли закрывающий break? Говорили нужен цикл, а какой именно if else, while или for? Извиняюсь за может глупые вопросы, я только учусь, а в PHP справочнике трудно понять без базы данных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете вывести из исходного массива несколько элементов и удалить их после вывода, а в другом блоке ниже, вы снова перебираете этот-же массив но уже в нем ну будет выведенных ранее элементов.

Второй вариант решения данной проблемы как правильно заметил **splash58** и я полагаю дал вам ответ в предыдущем вашем вопросе это использовать [`array_splice`](http://www.php.su/array_splice) вы просто можете брать нужные вам элементы и скажем 1-ый раз перебрать первые 2 от массива а второй раз все остальные исключая первые два.

```html
<?php if($brands): ?>
<div class="block-content">
  <div class="container cf">
    <div class="large b-row cf">
      <!-- Здесь выводится 2 первые заметки, С БАЗЫ БЕРУТСЯ ВСЕ ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ БЕЗ limit=2!!!-->
      <!-- в foreach добавляем ключ $key -->
      <?php foreach($brands as $key => $brand): ?>
      <div class="column half b-col">
        <article>
          <a href="#"> </a>
          <h2 class="post-title"><a href="#"><?=$brand->title;?></a></h2>
          <div class="cf listing-meta meta below"> <span class="meta-item author"><?=$brand->title;?> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> 3</a></span></div>
          <div class="excerpt">
            <p>
              <?=$brand->description;?>
            </p>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
      <!-- в конце итерации, после того как элемент вывели удаляем его из исходного массива -->
      <?php unset($brands[$key]); ?>
      <!-- если мы вывесли 2 элемента то выходим из цикла -->
      <?php if($key >= 1) break; ?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <!--А как быть дальше и вывести еще 6 заметок из тойже таблицы ума неприлажу-->
    <ul class="b-row posts-list thumb">
      <!-- снова перебираем массив но уже в нем будут удалены выведеные выше объекты -->
      <?php foreach($brands as $brand): ?>
      <li class="column half b-col">
        <article class="post cf">
          <a href="#"> </a>
          <div class="content">
            <a href="#"><?=$brand->title;?></a>
            <div class="cf listing-meta below"> <time datetime="2017-01-10T03:34:37+00:00" class="meta-item">Jan 10, 2017</time></div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```